# displaying select dropdown in where clause but get failed data

Tags: laravel, select

I have 3 table  . this name is  aduan, ipsrs , teknisi

struckture aduan table

```
id 
user_id
ipsrs_id
teknisi_id
aduan
etc.....
```

ipsrs table

```
id
nama_bagian
etc....
```

teknisi table

```
id
ipsrs_id
nama_teknisi
etc...
```

this is have models like this

```
class Aduan extends Model {


use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'aduan';
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'ipsrs_id','nama_pengadu', 'aduan','teknisi_id'
];

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class ,'user_id');
    // return $this->HasMany(\App\User::class ,'user_id');
}


public function ipsrs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Ipsrs::class ,'ipsrs_id');
    // return $this->HasMany(\App\User::class ,'user_id');
}

public function teknisi()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Teknisi::class ,'teknisi_id');
    // return $this->HasMany(\App\User::class ,'user_id');
}
```

Teknisi Model

```
class Teknisi extends Model {
protected $table = 'teknisi';
protected $fillable = [
    'ipsrs_id', 'nama_teknisi', 'bagian',
];


public function ipsrs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Ipsrs::class ,'ipsrs_id');
    // return $this->HasMany(\App\User::class ,'user_id');
}}
```

with this table i want to create select dropdown on the modal . 
i create select dropdown using pluck , this data is showing but not like what iam need . 
its in the controller

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $ipsrs = DB::table('ipsrs')->pluck('nama_bagian','id');

    $belum_kerjakan = Aduan::with('users')->where('status','Belum Dikerjakan')->get();
    $teknisi        = Teknisi::pluck('nama_teknisi', 'id')->where('ipsrs_id' , $request->ipsrs_id); // this is to get pluck teknisi where this id ( ipsrs_id on **teknisi**) same like ipsrs_id on aduan ( if you see this table ,you will see this ipsrs_id in two table , but its didnt work and **show all data**)  
    $dalam_proses   = Aduan::with('users')->where('status','Sedang Dikerjakan')->get();
    $selesai        = Aduan::with('users')->where('status','Selesai')->get();
    return view('admin.admin_dashboard',[
        'belum_dikerjakan' => $belum_kerjakan,
        'dalam_proses'     => $dalam_proses,
        'selesai'          => $selesai,
        'ipsrs'            => $ipsrs,
        'teknisi'          => $teknisi,
    ]);

}
```

in my conclusion how i can get this pluck data in where clause like that ?

```
$teknisi        = Teknisi::pluck('nama_teknisi', 'id')->where('ipsrs_id' , $request->ipsrs_id);
```

only data where ipsrs_id (on teknisi) is same like ipsrs_id (on aduan)

Answer (score 0):

`Pluck` helper method is used to extract the data from the given array/object of results not to filter. So add the filter `where` before extracting it.

```
$teknisi = Teknisi::select('nama_teknisi', 'id')->where('ipsrs_id', $request->ipsrs_id)->pluck('nama_teknisi', 'id');
```

Comment: Wait i will try

Comment: its not displaying data

Comment: This was the only problem I could find in your code and check with db for ipsrs_id in teknisi table

Comment: This problem is $request->ipsrs_id . I change this with '1' its showing a true value , how i can catch this ipsrs_id on the form ?